# Run for loop on all processors and increment a single variable in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have a function `sim` that takes quite long to compute. I need to run a simulation and then check some condition to increment a single variable.

```
switches = 0
@showprogress 1 "Computing ..."  for i = 1:100
    m0 = data[i]
    m = sim(data[i])
    if allSwitch(m0, m)
        switches += 1
    end
end
```

How can I run this on multiple processors? I don't quite understand how to use `pmap` or `@parallel` in this case, especially since I need to increment `switches` and I don't know if the jobs have access to that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a parallel run, you usually do not want your processes to write to the same location. For example, when the current value of `switches` is 0 and two processes wants to increment the `switches` at the same time, they will both read switches as 0 and will increment it to 1 whereas you want `switches` to be 2 in this case. This is known as the *coherence* issue in parallel computing. You may want to use *atomic access-modify operations* to such variables but this serializes your program in the region that uses atomic operations and hence deteriorates the parallel performance.

In your case, there are several ways to work-around the coherence issue. One such way is that each of your process may store its own `switches` and then at the end of the parallel execution you sum all `switches` up and get the final result which is known as *the reduction operation*. To do that in Julia, you may create a `SharedArray` and each of your processes writes to the its own index (each process has a unique id given by `myid()`). Or instead you can simply use `@distributed` (`@parallel` in  0.6) macro to achieve that easily.

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4) # adds 4 processes

switches = @distributed (+) for i = 1:100
    m0 = data[i]
    m = sim(data[i])

    allSwitch(m0, m) # this is the value to be added to `switches` since it is already binary it will increment switches if `allSwitch` returns true
end
```

We specify the reduction operation as summation with `(+)`. You should remove `using Distributed` and replace `@distributed` with `@parallel` if your version of julia is 0.6.

In Julia 1.0, with `@distributed` your loops has read access to the outside variables, but for write access you should create a `SharedArray`. However, in your case it is not needed.

Here is another example that sums up even number in an array:

```
function sumeven(data)
    evensum = @distributed (+) for i = 1:length(data)
        if data[i] % 2 == 0
            data[i] # if even add data[i] to the sum
        else
            0 # if not add 0
        end # you can instead write `ifelse(data[i] % 2 == 0, data[i], 0)`
    end

    evensum
end

# try evensum
d = rand(1:100, 10000) # creates a random integer array of size 10000 selected from 1 to 100.
parallel_result = evensum(d)
```

Another way is to use `pmap`. You can write a function which handles what is inside your for loop for given `data` instance. Then using this function with `pmap` and your `data`, will give you a `BitArray` which holds for which indices `allSwitch` evaluated to be true. Than you can use `count` function to compute how many times it returned true. It is important to note that `pmap` by default distribute tasks one-by-one to processes(controlled by `batch_size` parameter)  while `@distributed` distributes the tasks as huge chunks. If the time it takes for each task is large and uneven, you should consider using `pmap` instead of `@distributed`.

You should take a look at the documentation for Parallel Computing in Julia.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing/#

Comment: I'm still having some trouble getting it up and running. Could you perhaps post a very simple working example? Just with a function that constantly returns true and increments switches? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: The above example should be working for you. The last value that appears in the `@distributed` loop adds up into the `switches` variable. In the above example it is the value returned by your `allSwitch` function. If allSwitch returns true it effectively increments `switches` by 1 since `true` is  1 otherwise if it returns false it adds  0 to `switches`. I added another example that sums up even numbers in a given array.